# Why does new ActionView for file have a black background

Tags: android, xamarin

When I select the app to open my file, it opens with a black background (same as my app).  I want it to open in it's default form, should be a white background with black text.  My app uses a black background.  Does that background carry through to the new Intent?  The PDF Reader that receives the intent takes on the background color of the Sending App, why?  How do I change that?

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "myauthority", file);

            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            target.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            target.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.NoHistory);

            Intent intent = Intent.CreateChooser(target, "Open File");
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            try
            {
                if (target.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) != null)
                {
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Unable to open PDF, check documents folder.", ex);
            }
```

Comment: Can you please post your demo that can reproducing your issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the CreateChooser intent and Start the Activity with just the target.

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "myauthority", file);

            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            target.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            target.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.NoHistory | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

            //Intent intent = Intent.CreateChooser(target, "Open File");
            //intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            try
            {
                if (target.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) != null)
                {
                    //StartActivity(intent);
                    StartActivity(target);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Unable to open PDF, check documents folder.", ToastLength.Short);
                throw new System.Exception("Unable to open PDF, check documents folder.", ex);
            }
```